How to use the CSS adjacent selector based on nested child classes?
I can use the adjacent selector like this:


/* When c and c are adjacent, color the second c red */

.c + .c {
  background-color: red;
}

But how to do the same thing when the ".c" is nested?
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c"></div>
  </div>
</div>

/* Does not work */
.a .b .c + .a .b .c {
  background-color: red;
}


For adjacent selector +, the two selectors must be on the same level.
So it must be .a + .a, since they are the only adjacent elements in your snippet. Then you can select the second .a's child element: .a + .a .b .c. After that you could restrict the first .a to make sure it also has child elements .b .c using :has() pseudo class:
.a:has(.b .c) + .a .b .c



.a:has(.b .c) + .a .b .c {
  background-color: red;
}
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">1</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">
    <div class="c">2</div>
  </div>
</div>




Very nice. Worked perfectly. Thanks for sharing your expertise and teaching me about :has!

Glad it helped. Just a quick note that if you're working with legacy browsers like Internet Explorer etc., this would not work that :has() is a relatively new feature.

In that case you can't access .c directly by adjacent selector.
Because the adjacent sibling selector is used to select an element that is directly after another specific element. Sibling elements must have the same parent element, and "adjacent" means "immediately following".
So, in this case you can use + for targeting .a and then .c like below:


.a + .a .b .c{
    background-color: red;
}
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">First C</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        <div class="c">Second C</div>
    </div>
</div>




You code doesn't work because in the CSS portion the adjacent sibling combinator (+) can select only the elements that are immediately siblings to the first specified element. So it's trying to select the .c elements that are directly after an other .c element, but in your code the two .c elements are placed in different parents so they can't be adiacent siblins like the (+) selector requires, in order to work with the + selector the two .c elements must be placed one after the other, in the same parent level. Please mark my answer i'm new i need rep. points
